# How to Setup Azure Alert for Failed Durable Function Orchestration?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-monitoring, azure-durable-functions, azure-alerts

I would like to be notified via an email alert when an unknown exception occurs in an activity function that is part of a durable orchestration chain.  The problem is that when an exception is thrown in an Activity Function, the logged error in Application Insights shows a status code of zero.  In Azure Alerts, there is no alert configuration that will look for a log message status code of zero, only 1xx, 2xx, 4xx, etc.  No matter what I've tried on code, I can't get the functions to return a 4xx of 5xx error code.

How can I setup in Azure Monitor Alert to catch a failed orchestration?  Is there a way to force a non-zero status code when an exception is thrown?

**Background Info**

As the following screenshot shows, Azure Monitor for the durable function is showing a failure, which is what I'm expecting...

[image]

However, I can't figure-out how to setup an alert to detect this failure.  Finding the exception in Application Insights, the response code that caused the failure is zero...

[image]

Going over to Azure Monitor Alerts, when setting-up a new alert to detect this condition, there is no such thing as an alert condition for a status code of zero (which makes sense, but doesn't help me)...

[image]

Here is a shell of the Activity Function that is intentionally throwing an exception to help me setup the alert and know it's working...

```
[FunctionName("SearchProductIndexFunctionActivity")]
public static async Task Run(
    [ActivityTrigger]string input,
    ILogger logger,
    ExecutionContext context)
{
    logger.LogInformation("Started SearchProductIndexFunctionActivity...");

    throw new ArgumentException("Oops...");

    logger.LogInformation("Finished SearchProductIndexFunctionActivity successfully.");
}
```

And here is the Orchestrator Function that calls the Activity Function.  If all exceptions are not caught and rethrown, the Orchestrator Function shows a "success" status which isn't helpful... I want to know something failed.  However, the response status code of zero that results from this exception doesn't help setup the alert.   Any suggestions on how to fix this?

```
[FunctionName("SearchOrchestration")]
public static async Task Run(
    [OrchestrationTrigger]DurableOrchestrationContext orchestrationContext,
    ExecutionContext context,
    ILogger logger)
{
    try
    {
        await orchestrationContext.CallActivityAsync(PART_INDEX_UPDATE_ACTIVITY_NAME, null);

        await orchestrationContext.CallActivityAsync(PRODUCT_INDEX_UPDATE_ACTIVITY_NAME, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        logger.LogError(ex, $"Search index orchestration failed.");
        throw;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Application insights, you can consider using create a **custom log search alert** as per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log#create-a-log-alert-rule-with-the-azure-portal).

For "Resource", you should select the application insights used for the azure function.

For "Condition", select the "Custom log search". Then in the "Search query" textbox, you can write a query. In your case, the error should in the exception table of application insights, so the query looks like `exceptions | your_query_for_error`.

---

If you are not familiar with the sql-like query in application insights, you can refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/log-query/log-query-overview). And you can write your query in application insights first to make sure it can work as expected. A screenshot of query in application insights:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Ivan.  I didn't know about custom log search alerts.